# regex target specific character around variable

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi,

I have this code:

```
var room = 'room2';
var exitroom = 'room1,room2,room3';

exitroom = exitroom.replace(/,${room},/,'');

console.log(exitroom);
```

you can try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/uq9w0Ls4/

my expected output is simply `room1,room3` by taking `room2` out but since it may change its position within the string I want to target the `,` no matter if it comes before or after the string but I cant figure out the regex logic here. I know I could just do simply:

```
var room = 'room2';
var exitroom = 'room1,room2,room3';

exitroom = exitroom.replace(room+',','').replace(','+room,'');

console.log(exitroom);
```

which works but I think regex would be a more direct approach.

Thank you.

Comment: You probably want ``exitroom = exitroom.replace(new RegExp(String.raw`,${room}\b|\b${room},`,'g'),'');``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, by writing `.replace(/,${room},/,'')` you are not using the variable room.

To use a variable in a regex you should call `new RegExp()`

Second, if you want a regex that will match when the comma is before or after the word, you can use a group `()` with an Or `|` operator.

so it should look like this:

```
var reg = new RegExp(`(?:${room},|,${room})`, "g");
exitroom.replace(reg,'');
```

The `?:` at the beginning of the group, is just so it should be a non-capturing group, it should work just fine also without it

Comment: Great explanation, thank you. What would be a non-capturing group in this case?

Comment: @CainNuke I'm not sure I understand your question. if you use `()` it is a capturing group. if you do not need to capture you can use `(?:)`. But yes if you want, you can still use `()` and just not do anything with the captured group.

Comment: A non-capturing group means that it matches what is in the group, but doesn't capture it to use later. A capturing group stores the result in $1, $2, ..., while a non-capturing doesn't. In addition, there are also named capturing groups that store the result in $name. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on that. I am still to get a hold of regex altogether so I didnt even know what a capturing group was until now. I took out all the ( to keep it simple.